# vba code to copy worksheets and paste as values to a new workbook

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I'm not very good at vba so excuse my amateur question.
I have an active workbook open containing 3 tabs. I want to build a macro that opens up another workbook and pastespecial values the data from my three tabs into the three tabs on the second workbook.

This is my coding which keeps breaking on the paste special line.

```
Sub NewVersion_Click()

Dim y As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fact Find").Range("A5:I283").Copy
Set y = Workbooks.Open("location")
y.Worksheets("Fact Find").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Entity Fact Find").Range("A4:F237").Copy
'y.Worksheets("Entity Fact Find").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Suitability Assessment Form").Range("A4:E108").Copy
'y.Worksheets("Suitability Assessment Form").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks
Arvin

Comment: Why don't just save your workbook as?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your paste special for worksheet fact find.
Modify the code to copy the other sheets, but no need to open the file again.
Which file are you trying to close?

```
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Sheets("Fact Find").Range("A5:I283").Copy
    Workbooks.Open ("location")
    Workbooks("location").Worksheets("Fact Find").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wb.Sheets("Entity Fact Find").Range("A4:F237").Copy
    Workbooks("location").Worksheets("Entity Fact Find").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```